# Separation of paired values into rows/columns for individual variables

Tags: r

Searched but haven't seen where this has been handled.I have a pairwise computation data frame of absolute differences between sites from a project and the data is like this

```
   x y value
1  2 1     5
2  3 1     4
3  4 1     6
4  5 1     3
5  3 2     5
6  4 2     7
7  5 2     3
8  4 3     2
9  5 3     5
10 5 4     7
```

where x and y are paired sites and value is the difference. I would like to get the results of mean **for each site** displayed separately. Eg. site mean of all  site 5 pairs (5|3, 5|4, 5|1, 5|2) = 4.5 so that my results will be like below:

```
site    avg 
   1    4.5
   2    5
   3    4
   4    5.5
   5    4.5
```

Whose got the solution?

Comment: are you looking for `aggregate(value ~ x, data = df, FUN = mean)`?

Comment: Thanks Jaap for the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` and `mapply`.

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(site = unique(c(df$x, df$y))) %>%
  mutate(mean =  mapply(function(v)mean(df$value[df$x==v | df$y==v]), .$site)) %>%
  arrange(site)

#   site mean
# 1    1  4.5
# 2    2  5.0
# 3    3  4.0
# 4    4  5.5
# 5    5  4.5
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"  x y value
1  2 1     5
2  3 1     4
3  4 1     6
4  5 1     3
5  3 2     5
6  4 2     7
7  5 2     3
8  4 3     2
9  5 3     5
10 5 4     7",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @blackie Thanks much for feedback. Since, you are relatively new member, hence I should point you to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   select(x, y) %>% 
   unlist %>% 
   unique %>% 
   sort %>% 
   tibble(site = .) %>% 
   mutate(avg = map_dbl(site, ~
             df %>% 
               filter_at(vars(x, y), any_vars(. == .x)) %>% 
               summarise(value = mean(value)) %>%
               pull(value)))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#   site  avg
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1   4.5
#2     2   5  
#3     3   4  
#4     4   5.5
#5     5   4.5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L), 
    y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), value = c(5L, 
    4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 7L)), .Names = c("x", "y", 
"value"), class = "data.frame",
   row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Hi akrun, got stuck using this solution as "Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : object 'x' not found"

Comment: @blackie  I am using `purrr_0.2.4`, `dplyr_0.7.5` on `R 3.4.4`  Could be some version difference?

Comment: I would n't think it's that. If the solution is framed in such a way as df$x... rather than ...select(x), I think it might work

Comment: @blackie For me, it is working fine with the data I showed.  So, I am not sure about the issue on your side

Answer (score 1):

If we name your original data example as `df`:

```
df$site_pair <- paste(df$x, df$y, sep = "-")
all_sites <- unique(c(df$x, df$y))
site_get_mean <- function(site_name) {
  yes <- grepl(site_name, df$site_pair)
  mean(df$value[yes])
}

df.new <- data.frame(site = all_sites, 
                     avg = sapply(all_sites, site_get_mean))
```

Result: (edited to order by site name)

```
> df.new[order(df.new$site), ]
  site avg
5    1 4.5
1    2 5.0
2    3 4.0
3    4 5.5
4    5 4.5
```

Comment: Awesome. It worked fine. Why is the output unordered?

Comment: that's the order that the sites appear in your data, 2, 3, 4, 5 in first column, then site 1 in the second column... added a line to change that